# Mysql not connecting with Django 1.11.7 using python 3.6

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using python 3.6 and install django 1.11.7. Its working fine with Oracle and Sqlite3. But not working with mysql.

To connect with mysql tried to install package Mysql-python but it showing error:

***Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging168/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in 
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging168/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in 
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

```
----------------------------------------***
```

- I guessed that i should download ConfigParser. But configparser itself showing error:

*Collecting configparse
No matching distribution found for configparse
equirement configparse (from versions: )*

Now i am stuck. Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to install MySQL properly with the following script.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

follow the instruction for complete the installation.

then install the following script.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then do this

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql-python is not supported for python 3.x, Install mysqlclient using the following command:

pip install mysqlclient

If you are connecting to a proxy in a corporate environment, then use the following command:

pip install mysqlclient --proxy=proxy:8080

Comment If you need help on using pip.